# Is having a single parent Ads Activity a good aproach to setup Ads in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I've setup the ads in my app in the following way:

I have the class AdsActivity which extends AppCompatActivity and only overrides onCreateMethod the following way:

```
public class AdsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity.NUMBER_OF_PAGES_VISITED++;
        initializeAds();
    }

    private void initializeAds() {
        ProductsHelper productsHelper = new ProductsHelper(this);
        if (!productsHelper.isProModeEnabled(this) && MainActivity.NUMBER_OF_PAGES_VISITED >= 5) {
            MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
            });
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("XXXX");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    super.onAdClosed();

                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded();
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                        MainActivity.NUMBER_OF_PAGES_VISITED = 0;
                    }
                }

            });
        }

    }

}
```

Following this pattern , I can easily add in any Activity using only 1 InterstitialAd shared by all this activities . However , is this a good practice in AdMob having only one AdUnit instead of multiple of the same type but with other unitsId ?

Comment: if you want to see reports/view per activity, then its good idea to create separate id per activity.

Comment: But if i'm only interested in the revenue , is it relevant to have only one ?

Comment: then only create one

Comment: I dont understand your answer . I have asked if will I be penalized in any way if I only use 1 AD.

Comment: Ohh.. sorry for that.. You will not be penalized in any way for using single ad on multiple activities. Please refer to this link for disallowed interstitial implementations https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287